# XML AUTO Parent or child?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

If I have a code like:

```
SELECT FullName, Country, OrderId, OrderDate, SaleAmount
FROM Orders 
JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId
WHERE Customers.CustomerId = 12345
FOR XML AUTO
```

It generates something along the lines of:

```
<Customers FullName="Bob" Country="Canada">
    <Orders OrderId="1" OrderDate="2014-02-02" SaleAmount="1000.00"/>
    <Orders OrderId="2" OrderDate="2014-06-08" SaleAmouont="450.00"/>
</Customers>
```

But what if I want to generate an XML like:

```
<Orders OrderId="1" OrderDate="2014-02-02" SaleAmount="1000.00">
    <Customers FullName=.../>
</Orders>
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(CustomerID INT, FullName VARCHAR(20), Country VARCHAR(20))
GO
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES 
(1, 'Bob', 'Canada')
GO
CREATE TABLE Orders(CustomerID INT, OrderID INT, OrderDate DATE, SalesAmount INT)
GO
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES
(1, 1, '20140202' , 1000),(1, 2, '20140608' , 450)
GO
```

### Query

```
SELECT  OrderId, OrderDate, SalesAmount
       ,(SELECT FullName [@FullName]
              , Country  [@Country]
         FROM Customers
         WHERE Orders.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId
         FOR XML PATH('Customers'), TYPE)
FROM Orders 
FOR XML AUTO
```

### Result

```
<Orders OrderId="1" OrderDate="2014-02-02" SalesAmount="1000">
  <Customers FullName="Bob" Country="Canada" />
</Orders>
<Orders OrderId="2" OrderDate="2014-06-08" SalesAmount="450">
  <Customers FullName="Bob" Country="Canada" />
</Orders>
```

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way to do this without PATH, but this is simple enough.